# Undestanding ORA-14196 when turning global index to local partitoned on Oracle 19.20

Tags: database, oracle19c, oracle

I have a table with an index on a foreign key column FK_COLUMN, the column has a unique constraint also.
On Oracle 19.3 I am paritioning the table by range on the primary key column, then I update the index above making it local.

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY 
PARTITION BY RANGE (ID_PK) (PARTITION P123 VALUES LESS THAN (123)) 
UPDATE INDEXES ( MY_INDEX LOCAL, *[other indexes become local]*);
```

If I run this statement on Oracle 19.20 I am getting ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.
(The sollution I found was leave this index global on Oracle 19.20.)

What I don't understant is this: if I run the statement on 19.3 and then upgrade the database to 19.20 then Oracle doesn't complain and it seems the index can be local and that the unique constraint also remains on the FK_COLUMN. Shouldn't there be an ORA-14196 (or another error) when I upgrade to 19.20?

Comment: Can't speak to the error not showing up in 19.20, but you can't have a unique index that is local without it including the partitioning key in the index column list. Redefine the index as non-unique., or make it global.

Comment: Thanks @PaulW, I got that and went for keeping the index global